# Dump individual text fields into separate files in psql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, psql, postgresql-8.4

I have a simple table "**id, name, content**" and I would like to export all the records in files named "*id_name.txt*" with content from the "content" column (text type). This will create as many files as necessary. How to do that in psql?

I was thinking something like this, but parsed does not like "arow.id" and "TO filename" syntax.

```
do $$
  declare
    arow record;
    filename varchar;
  begin
    for arow in
    select id, name, template from config_templates
    loop
      filename := '/tmp/' || arow.name || '.txt';
      COPY (select template from config_templates where id = arow.id) TO filename (FORMAT CSV); 
    end loop;
  end;
$$;
```

Comment: I wonder if you were trying to export foreman provisioning templates?  That is the exact use case I'm looking at that caused me to run across this exact question.  :)  Except now the table name is just "templates."

Comment: Was working on Foreman for 12 years, so I'd say - yeah. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be it is late for you but I found the solution in your question, so wanted to share my solution here. Your looped solution didn't work because COPY command waits filename as a string constant. My solution is using dynamic query with EXECUTE. Please pay attention to double single quotes in EXECUTE params.

```
do $$
  declare
    arow record;
    filename varchar;
  begin
    for arow in
    select id, name, template from config_templates 
    loop
      filename := '/tmp/' || arow.name::character varying(100) || '.txt';
      EXECUTE format('COPY (select template from config_templates where id = ''%s'' ) TO ''%s'' (FORMAT CSV)', arow.id::character varying(100), filename); 
    end loop;
  end;
$$;
```

Answer (score 2):

Take psql console and type

```
\COPY table_name(column_name) TO 'path_of_text_file';
```

Comment: Actually, this is pretty close, COPY does support a query, so if I am able to use this in a loop, then I could export this one by one. Edited my question with the pseudo-code.